# MYSQL selecting top 4 sums based on criteria

Tags: mysql

Hoping you will be able to help me with this MYSQL statement. I have a table like so:

```
    |id            |duration     |start               |
    |1110460       |8.2          |20171211            |
    |2221104       |8.9          |20171112            |
    |1110460       |3.2          |20171113            |
    |1110460       |4.4          |20171214            |
    |3331938       |3.2          |20180115            |
    |3331722       |5.4          |20171216            |
    |1948212       |9.2          |20171217            |
    |9219302       |3.2          |20171218            |
```

What I want to do is list the top 4 IDs by total duration for a given start month in descending order.

For example, for the top 4 IDs for 201712:

```
    |id            |duration     |
    |1110460       |12.6         |
    |1948212       |9.2          |
    |3331722       |5.4          | 
    |9219302       |3.2          |
```

Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far, but it has been returning the incorrect results:

```
    SELECT id, sum(duration) FROM table WHERE 
    start LIKE '201712%' ORDER BY sum(duration) DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: You probably want to use ORDER BY MAX(duration), not SUM

Comment: Have you tried enclosing _"start"_ in backticks as the following; \`start\`?Since start is a keyword.

Comment: What if 2 or more ids have same sum result? Like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56d9be/1 or you need distinct sum result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use group by

```
SELECT id, sum(duration) 
FROM table 
WHERE start LIKE '201712%' 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY sum(duration) DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Silly me! Forgot the group by. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get 4 distinct maximum sums and their ids you could use following

```
SELECT a.id, a.sum_duration 
FROM (SELECT id, sum(duration) sum_duration
      FROM demo 
      WHERE `start` LIKE '201712%' 
      GROUP BY id
) a
JOIN (SELECT distinct sum(duration) max_durations
      FROM demo 
      WHERE `start` LIKE '201712%' 
      GROUP BY id
      ORDER BY sum(duration) DESC 
      LIMIT 4 
) b on a.sum_duration = b.max_durations
```

The above version will return morethan 4 rows if 2 ids have same result of sum

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56d9be/5)